# Finding diagonizable $n×n$ matrix $A$ with $p(\lambda)=\lambda^{k}(1-\lambda)^{n-k}$, $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $0≤k≤n$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Full problem:
Suppose that$ A $is a diagonalizable $ n \times n$ matrix such that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^{k} (1-\lambda)^{n-k}$ , where $k$ is a positive integer such that $0 \leq k \leq  n$. Prove $A^2 = A$.

I am not quite sure how to prove this while incorporating the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a basis made up of eigen vectors. From the characteristic polynomial we know that the only eigen values are $0$ and $1$.
If $v$ is an eigen vector corresponding to the eigen value $1$, then
$$A^2(v)=A(v)$$
Same holds for the zero eigen value.

Comment: thanks, so from A = PDP^(-1) , D=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
and D^2=D , so A = P D^(2) P^(-1) = P D P^(-1) = A

Comment: is this a valid proof?

Comment: correction****   A^2 = P D^(2) P^(-1)